# Minimum viscosity of liquids

Tags: fluid-dynamics, specific-reference, viscosity

In a [lecture by Purcell](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/gold/pdfs/purcell.pdf) he mentions that he notices that there aren't any liquids with viscosities much less than that of water, even though they go up seemingly unbounded. In an endnote (endnote 1 in that copy), he mentioned that Weisskopf found a reason, but I haven't been able to find what that reason actually was.

Note that this is *not* about the AdS-CFT lower bound.

Comment: About the comment of Purcell in "Life at low Reynolds number", you will find your answer here: https://ccmmp.ph.qmul.ac.uk/~kostya/The%20Purcell%20question.pdf ("The quantum mechanics of viscosity"
Kostya Trachenko and Vadim V. Brazhkin  Physics Today 74, 12, 66 (2021)  https://doi.org/10.1063/PT.3.4908 )

Answer (score 4):

If "not much less than water" means "not an order of magnitude lower than water at room temperature" this is probably correct. However there are substances like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentane with a viscosity 4 times less than that of water or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acetone with a viscosity 3 times less than water (at 20 degrees celcius). At lower temperatures (77K) you find liquid nitrogen with an viscosity less than 5 times that of water at room temperature. On the other side at 1K helium becomes a superfluid with effectively zero viscosity http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superfluid_helium-4) In that sense viscosity seems to behave similar to electric resistance, being lower with lower temperature. So without reading Weisskopf I guess it's simply room temperature which provides an lower limit to the viscosity of a fluid.